# Can the reticulate package display images in IPython.display?

Tags: python, rstudio, reticulate

I have this code:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Kosaciec_szczecinkowaty_Iris_setosa.jpg'
(Image(url,width=300, height=300))
```

When I put the code in a jupyter notebook it displayed the image but in RStudio with Reticulate it only displays:

"IPython.core.display.Image object"

I have tried putting the image into a variable and running either show() or display(), but it returns: 
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'show/display'

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Judah Drelich, did you figure out how to display images in r with reticulate?

Comment: It's been a long time, so I don't remember if I got it to run. I am using VS Code and Python now, so it isn't an issue.